# No touch screen Ubuntu 22.04.3 Surface Pro 3

Tags: dual-boot, touchscreen

I am trying to dual boot Win10/Ubuntu on an old Surface Pro 3 (1796) (Intel Core i5-7300U, 8GB Ram). After installation, Ubuntu boots just fine, but I cannot use the touch screen. I then run the commands to install the Linux-Surface kernel and grub (here: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup). When I reboot, the machine hangs and I cannot boot into either (this is a different problem). I have tried running Manjaro, Ubuntu, PopOS and none of them support touch out of the box.

Can someone please help me?